# IOS 8 Bluetooth BLE Peripheral reconnect takes too long ( hours)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios8, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Application working fine on IOS 7, after upgrade to IOS 8 the it takes hour to the device to reconnect to a disconnected peripheral.

The reconnect command is sent inside the centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error: delegate

Comment: Is this in the background or the foreground?  Can you show your code?  I have BT code that sounds the same as yours and it reconnects immediately under ios8

Comment: It's in the background. On IOS7 the devices reconnect in less than 1 second, sometime longer up to 15 seconds. On IOS8 it takes hours.

Comment: You can compare your code with my example - https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground it reconnects immediately

Comment: We have pretty much the same code. The only different is that you passing options:nil to the connectPeripheral:peripheral:options and I’m passing: options = @{ CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey : @YES        CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey: @YES}

Comment: If you set those options then iOS will display an alert to the user prompting them to open your app. How are you putting your app in the background? Are you just pressing the home button or are you swiping up from the task switcher?

Comment: Pressing the home button. We were able to isolate the problem to iPhone 6. iPhone 5 running IOS8 is doing well.